# How can I remove an unnamed advice?

Tags: advice

I was having fun adding some advice to a function:

```el
(advice-add 'executable-find :around
            (lambda (f &rest args)
              (apply g args)))
               ;;;   ^
```

Ouch, a typo. Fixed it and evaluated above code again. **But now I have both, the "corrected" and the "broken" advice around that function.**

*How do I get rid of these? Given that `advice-remove` needs either the function object or the around advice (which is empty here)?*

(Obviously I can just quit and restart, but there's another way, is it?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also call `advice-remove` with the same lambda expression, i.e., replace `advice-add` with `advice-remove` and delete `:around`, then <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>.

Comment: This works! I thought it wouldn't, I assumed that (1) each time you evaluate a lambda form you get a new function not `eq` to the previous ones, (2) advice-remove would compare the function you pass it to the advices until it finds one that is `eq` to it and remove that, (3) even if advice-remove used a different test, like `equal`, it still wouldn't work, because different evaluations of a lambda form would not `equal` each other. Turns out (1) is correct, but (2) and (3) are wrong: advice-remove uses `equal`, and evaluating the same `lambda` twice produces `equal` results!

Comment: Noticed I didn't accept an answer back when I asked the question. I choose Yours because it's the IMO most helpful in the situation.

Answer (score 12):

There's `advice-mapc`, which let's one iterate over all advices of some function, applying a given function to each. With it, it's easy to remove all advices:

```el
(advice-mapc
  (lambda (adv prop)
    (advice-remove 'executable-find adv))
  'executable-find)
```

This could be extended to remove only advices which don't have a `name` property by looking in the second (`props`) argument (which is an alist) for those which do not have something associated to key `name`.

Comment: Yes. And using a `name` makes removing easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to help doing just that, interactively.

This defines two functions. The first function gets the list of all advices on a given symbol, the second function interactively asks for a symbol and an advice on that symbol, then removes the latter from the former. As this all happens with completion, it's easier (to me) than copy pasting the lambda expression.

```el
(defun yf/advice-list (symbol)
  (let (result)
    (advice-mapc
     (lambda (ad props)
       (push ad result))
     symbol)
    (nreverse result)))

(defun yf/kill-advice (symbol advice)
  "Kill ADVICE from SYMBOL."
  (interactive (let* ((sym (intern (completing-read "Function: " obarray #'yf/advice-list t)))
                      (advice (let ((advices-and-their-name
                                     (mapcar (lambda (ad) (cons (prin1-to-string ad)
                                                                ad))
                                             (yf/advice-list sym))))
                                (cdr (assoc (completing-read "Remove advice: " advices-and-their-name nil t)
                                            advices-and-their-name)))))
                 (list sym advice)))
  (advice-remove symbol advice))
```