# How to find out what advice has been defined for a function?

Tags: advice

I accidentally added a lambda function that wasn't done being written to the advice of a function, and the function doesn't work. I don't know the exact text of the lambda function. Obviously, I could fix the problem by restarting emacs, but I don't want to have to do that.

**How do I get a list of advice defined for a function so I can remove the lambda function?**

Comment: And yes, I have decided that advising with lambda functions is a bad idea. It would still be interesting to know how to get a list.

Comment: Should be easy enough to modify [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33021/5296) to remove just the advice you want.